# How does Tomohiko Sakamoto's Algorithm, for finding the day of week, work?

Tags: c++

How does the following algorithm work?

```
enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
};

static DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeek(unsigned int year, char month, char day) {
    char monthTable[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 };

    year -= (unsigned int)((month < 3) ? 1 : 0);

    return (DayOfWeek)((year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400 + monthTable[month - 1] + day) % 7);
}
```

source is [here](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/day-of-week?lang=C%2B%2B)

Can someone explain why does it work and how?

Comment: This code was invented by People who worked around a Long time for this... Just accept that it works :-) It's more or less the same like calulating eastern. If you are interested in those algorithms, there are many articles out there. e.g. check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: The computation with the `year` is to check leap year. the month table is the offset by month (as January has 31 days (`31 == 4 * 7 + 3`, February begin the week with that offset `3`)).

Comment: @ThomasSparber why it is overcomplicated then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `t[]` holds offsets for each month (in relation to 1st January), while the `/4` `/100` `/400` account for leap years and double leap years.

You can find a quite detailed explanation of this particular algorithm here: https://www.quora.com/How-does-Tomohiko-Sakamotos-Algorithm-work

Comment: Here is another article on same subject: http://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/get-day-of-week-from-date

Answer (score 0):

Hm, why not simply use `tm->tm_wday`?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: The question was not, if he should use that code, but how it works. If it is done well, the ctime library as well as `std::chrono` should have an implementation similar to the one in the question. BTW.: I think, we should better educate people to use C++ standard libraries instead of C libraries in C++ questions. So I'd prefer `std::chrono` here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this solution is chosen but I think calculate week day based on Julian day - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day is significantly simpler:

> The US day of the week W1 can be determined from the Julian Day Number J with the expression:
>     W1 = mod(J + 1, 7)[28]

Converting formula for date to Julian day is similar to shown, but does not require table nor conditional subtraction:

[image]

Comment: Not sure it is simpler to understand with those magic numbers.

Comment: @Jarod42 You do not have to understand it, but this formula is simpler to implement and definitely would be faster as does not require conditional operators. Also Julian day is useful for other purpose, for example to calculate time difference btw dates.